# Why can't some characters use their abilities?

Tags: marvel-ultimate-alliance-3

I'm trying out a bunch of characters in Marvel Ultimate Alliance 3, but I'm having trouble figuring out why some characters seemingly can't use their abilities at all.

For example, Scarlet Witch and Spiderman never have their ability icon active. Even while trying to press R+Y just a basic attack comes out. However, with others like Hulk and Crystal, they have their abilities available to use when the blue bar is full, and unavailable otherwise.

Are there other requirements for using some abilities? How can I use abilities on these other characters?

Comment: Is there a chance that those characters can switch into a different style/state and use those abilities then?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there are two ways to activate abilities. You can use either ZR or R to bring up the abilities menu.

ZR only lets you use the ability if another ally who has synergy with that ability is also ready to use their ability.

R lets you use the ability alone, as long as you have the energy.

Use R instead of ZR to use an ability alone.